# Election time zone?

Tags: discussion, timezone

The elections say they start in one hour, which I'm assuming will be 4 p.m. my time (EST, US). They say they start at 20:00 (8 p.m) though, what time zone does this operate in?

Answer (score 11):

The same timezone everything else operates in, UTC.

Comment: gotcha! And thanks for the quick response to the noob question :)

Answer (score 3):

Stack Exchange uses [UTC for all times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start) that I'm aware of. You can check the UTC time [from the dropdown by your name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62853/stack-exchange-sites-need-a-universal-clock-that-is-visible).